# Defining JavaScript function within PHP page

Tags: javascript, php, html, dom-events

I'm running into an issue with calling a JavaScript function from the `onclick` event of a span object.

Here is the span object:

```
<td><span class="button" onclick="submitUser();">Save</span></td>
```

Here is the JavaScript function that I am trying to embed at the top of the PHP page that the save button is found on:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    submitUser = function()
    {
        alert('hello');
    }

</script>
```

I keep getting the JavaScript error:

> "Uncaught reference error: submitUser() is not defined"

If I define the JavaScript function on the same page as the save button. But if I put the function definition on the page calling the page containing the save button, the function works just fine. Is there a way that I can get that function in the the save button's page scope. I really don't want to have to load that function into memory every time the page calling the save button page is loaded, which is currently the only way I can get this to work.

Comment: Could you please add the php file with the relevant code? I'd like to see it in context.

Comment: Can you add the stripped down version of the php page?

Comment: What do you mean "the top of the php page" ? Put your script in the html head.

Comment: I could be wrong but I don't think you should have the semicolon after sumbitUser().

Comment: @Jared: this doesn't change anything

Comment: not sure relevant, but why are you using a form like `submitUser = function() {...}` ?  Why not just `function submitUser() {...}` ?  If you stick with the former, perhaps you need a `var` keyword.  It could be the missing `var` that is causing the function to remain undefined. I just tried on http://jsfiddle.net/vgvZw/ and the form you have works fine in Firefox. So perhaps you are not correctly embedding the script in the page.

Comment: Putting the script into html head did not work. The form of `submitUser = function()` is just the way I was taught and have always done it. That is the way I have it defined in the outer page call where the function works.

Comment: are u using internet explorer? the same thing happens in, lets say, firefox?

Comment: I'm using firefox and chrome, same behavior in both.

Comment: try onclick="javascript:submitUser();" attribute, although i am with Cheeso function submitUser(){} is how you supposed to write functions JS

Comment: try putting var in front, if that doesn't work try just defining the function submitUser:
function submitUser() {
}

Comment: Ya I changed it to function submitUser(){...} but that did not have any affect. When you say 'try putting var in front', what do you mean by that? Sorry..

Comment: im sorry but the point here is that you dont want to <script src='myjs.js'></script> to avoid memory consumption?

Comment: No the point isn't memory consumption in the way that you are saying. It's just that the only way I can get the function to be defined is by including the function in an outer page where the function isn't used rather than just defining it on the page where it will be used.

Comment: Could you please add some php code? It could help us understand your problem.

Comment: maybe the php code that *prints* the javascript function and script tags is not printed or not parsed correctly, not closing  a tag may result to that.. provide more information ...

Comment: I removed all php and now have a html file that contains just he button and the .js function. I think I'm just going to have to resort to putting the function in the outer file. That is the only way I can get it to be defined.

Comment: So, you have really made up your mind about not giving us more information, right?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<script>
function submitUser() {
    alert("hello!");
}
</script>
```

and this:

```
<span onclick="javascript:submitUser()">Save</span>
```